# Using Google Maps API with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API with Meteor 1.3 and with the dburles:google-maps package.

I tried various way to load it but the thing is that I can't use it because it takes too long to load I think and my page is rendered before.

I load it this way in my `main.js` to be sure that is loaded first.

```
import { GoogleMaps } from 'meteor/dburles:google-maps';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(function () {
  GoogleMaps.load({ key: 'myKey' });
});
```

Then I include the helper in my template to display the map.

```
<template name="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>

    <div class="map-container">
        {{> googleMap name="exampleMap" options=exampleMapOptions}}
    </div>

</template>
```

Finally there is my helper to set the options for the template.

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { GoogleMaps } from 'meteor/dburles:google-maps';

import './home_page.html';

Template.home.helpers({
  exampleMapOptions() {
    // Make sure the maps API has loaded
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      // Map initialization options
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
        zoom: 8,
      };
    }
  },
});

Template.home.onCreated(function() {
  GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', function(map) {
    console.log("I'm ready!");
  });
});
```

I think that the condition `if (GoogleMaps.loaded())` is the reason why nothing is displayed but if I dont put it I got an error because the `google` object doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you have an error in the console JS?

Comment: Did you try to import google from the package as well?

Comment: @GUISSOUMAIssam No I don't have any.

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma I don't know if there is a Google package available. The documentation of the Google Maps package never specified any dependencies.

Comment: try to add the css on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have an error on your JS console, the map could be loaded but not shown for missing css.

If it's so, Add the line below to your `main.css`

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.map-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```